# How can I exclude an element from the focus outline for it's parent <div> element

Tags: css

I'm attempting to modify the outline of a `<div>` element when it receives focus via tabbing through the form. The `<div>` element is used as a button and contains a click event. The `<div>` element contains two children an `<svg>` and `<span>`. The `<span>` is used for a tooltip.

[image: Div outline including Span Element]

And the markup is like this:

```css
.iconButton {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #0E9AEF;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  user-select: none;
}

.iconButton svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  fill: white;
}

.iconButton polygon {
  fill: white;
}

.labelButton {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.labelButton .iconButton {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.labelButton .iconButton svg {
  height: 80%;
  width: 60%;
}

.iconButton {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.iconButton .toolTipText {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #08090A;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 120%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: auto;
}

.iconButton .toolTipText::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #08090A transparent transparent transparent;
}

.iconButton:hover .toolTipText {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="iconButton" id="saveButton" tabindex="14">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 792;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0 {
        clip-path: url(#SVGID_2_);
        fill: #FFFFFF;
      }
    </style>
    <g>
      <g>
        <defs>
          <rect height="512" id="SVGID_1_" width="512" x="50" y="140"></rect>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
          <use style="overflow:visible;" xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"></use>
        </clipPath>
        <path class="st0" d="M562,619V254l0,0c-0.1-2.9-1.2-6.1-4.1-9L457.4,144.5c0,0-5.3-4.9-11.7-4.5l0,0H83c0,0-33,0-33,33v446    c0,0,0,33,33,33h446C529,652,562,652,562,619L562,619z M453,303c0,22-22,22-22,22H181c-22,0-22-22-22-22V198c0-22,22-22,22-22h250    c22,0,22,22,22,22V303L453,303z M526,594c0,22-22,22-22,22H108c-22,0-22-22-22-22V394c0-22,22-22,22-22h396c22,0,22,22,22,22V594    L526,594z M435,296v-91c0,0,0-15-15-15h-49c0,0-15,0-15,15v91c0,0,0,15,15,15h49C420,311,435,311,435,296L435,296z"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span class="toolTipText">Save</span>
</div>
```

I've tried to define the following in the css

```
.iconButton .toolTipText:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

And various other permutations attempting to exclude the span from the outline that gets created surrounding the button. No variations of this have worked thus far.

**EDIT - Final Solution**

Thanks to @Creaforge for the guidance we came up with the following resolution. It should be noted that in the snippet editor / viewer the outline is outside the button... but in Chrome it is properly surrounding the button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUVjb.png)

```css
.iconButton {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background: #0E9AEF;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 5px;
 user-select: none;
 position: relative;
 outline: none;
}

 .iconButton:focus svg {
  outline: auto;
 }

 .iconButton svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15% 0;
  fill: white;
 }

 .iconButton polygon {
  fill: white;
 }

 .iconButton .toolTipText {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #08090A;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 120%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: auto;
 }

  .iconButton .toolTipText::after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -5px;
   border-width: 5px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #08090A transparent transparent transparent;
  }

 .iconButton:hover .toolTipText {
  visibility: visible;
 }
```

```html
<div class="iconButton" id="saveButton" tabindex="14">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 792;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0 {
        clip-path: url(#SVGID_2_);
        fill: #FFFFFF;
      }
    </style>
    <g>
      <g>
        <defs>
          <rect height="512" id="SVGID_1_" width="512" x="50" y="140"></rect>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
          <use style="overflow:visible;" xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"></use>
        </clipPath>
        <path class="st0" d="M562,619V254l0,0c-0.1-2.9-1.2-6.1-4.1-9L457.4,144.5c0,0-5.3-4.9-11.7-4.5l0,0H83c0,0-33,0-33,33v446    c0,0,0,33,33,33h446C529,652,562,652,562,619L562,619z M453,303c0,22-22,22-22,22H181c-22,0-22-22-22-22V198c0-22,22-22,22-22h250    c22,0,22,22,22,22V303L453,303z M526,594c0,22-22,22-22,22H108c-22,0-22-22-22-22V394c0-22,22-22,22-22h396c22,0,22,22,22,22V594    L526,594z M435,296v-91c0,0,0-15-15-15h-49c0,0-15,0-15,15v91c0,0,0,15,15,15h49C420,311,435,311,435,296L435,296z"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span class="toolTipText">Save</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The div does have a set width and height but the addition of the span within that div and how it's composed modifies this. See updated code snippet above.

I'll move the span used for the tooltip into it's own div and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can.

First you need to disable the outline from your parent element.
Then when the parent is focused, show the outline on the child, like so :

```
.parent {
    outline: none;
}

.parent:focus .children{
    outline: auto; /* Or whatever outline style you need */
}
```

Here is your updated markup :

```css
.iconButton {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background: #0E9AEF;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 5px;
 user-select: none;
 position: relative;
 outline: none;
}

.iconButton:focus svg{
 outline: auto;
}

.iconButton svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 70%;
 padding:15% 0;
 fill: white;
}

.iconButton polygon {
 fill: white;
}

.labelButton .iconButton {
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.labelButton .iconButton svg {
 height: 80%;
 width: 60%;
}


.iconButton .toolTipText {
 visibility: hidden;
 background-color: #08090A;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 5px 12px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 bottom: 120%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: normal;
 width: auto;
}

.iconButton .toolTipText::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -5px;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #08090A transparent transparent transparent;
}

.iconButton:hover .toolTipText {
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="iconButton" id="saveButton" tabindex="14">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 792;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
     clip-path: url(#SVGID_2_);
     fill: #FFFFFF;
    }
   </style>
 <g>
  <g>
   <defs>
    <rect height="512" id="SVGID_1_" width="512" x="50" y="140"></rect>
   </defs>
   <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
    <use style="overflow:visible;" xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"></use>
   </clipPath>
   <path class="st0" d="M562,619V254l0,0c-0.1-2.9-1.2-6.1-4.1-9L457.4,144.5c0,0-5.3-4.9-11.7-4.5l0,0H83c0,0-33,0-33,33v446    c0,0,0,33,33,33h446C529,652,562,652,562,619L562,619z M453,303c0,22-22,22-22,22H181c-22,0-22-22-22-22V198c0-22,22-22,22-22h250    c22,0,22,22,22,22V303L453,303z M526,594c0,22-22,22-22,22H108c-22,0-22-22-22-22V394c0-22,22-22,22-22h396c22,0,22,22,22,22V594    L526,594z M435,296v-91c0,0,0-15-15-15h-49c0,0-15,0-15,15v91c0,0,0,15,15,15h49C420,311,435,311,435,296L435,296z"></path>
  </g>
 </g>
  </svg>
<span class="toolTipText">Save</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep I saw that... Check on my code snippet : the outline is correct. You have to add a padding to the svg to expand the outline around your icon, like so : `.iconButton svg { padding:15% 0;}`

Comment: Actually that padding merely shrinks the image and leaves the border in the same place.

Comment: Okay the resolution was change the height of the .iconButton svg { height: 100%; }. With the padding this puts the icons into a closer size than before and achieves the goal of the proper outline for tab and hover when the div has focus. And it the span that contains the tooltip is not outlined. I'll mark your answer as correct once I update the question with the final solution.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because the focus belongs to the `div`, the `span` has no focus so it won't work. However you could create another element that is the child of the `div` and a sibling of the `span` and add the `outline` to that.

Comment: The code for the element is

   <div>
        <svg></svg>
        <span></span>
   </div>

I had attempted just setting the tabIndex and focus to the svg but the size is less than the div... and I wasn't able to find a method to increase the outline to match the parent element.

Comment: I believe no one will be able to fix your code until you provide a fully reproducible example in your question's body; the image was great, but we need something more dynamic.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code... Thanks for taking the time to help / take a look.